# Moving my public NPM package from Bitbucket to Github

Tags: github, npm, bitbucket

I like Bitbucket better than Github, but sadly there's only very few options for continuous integration for Bitbucket.

The packages in question are written by me, and are currently hosted on Bitbucket:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-asset-compress
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-file-parser

I want these to be moved to Github, without breaking anything. I am afraid changing the repository data is not enough.

```
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://StephanBijzitter@bitbucket.org/skelware/grunt-asset-compress.git"
  },
```

Image a user has version `1` installed, which is hosted on Bitbucket.
I then change the version to `2` and change the URL to the Github URL.
I proceed to push, to both Github and Bitbucket.
If the user updates, he will be updating to version `2`, which by now includes the URL of Github.
I push some more fixes and release version `3` on Github, the user updates again and everything is fine.

However, what if the user did not update to version `2`, before version `3` was released? NPM will probably try to download version `3` from Bitbucket as that is what the URL points to in version `1`!

I do not want to keep the repositories in sync; I want to be able to make the Bitbucket repository private at one point to hide it from public view while the Github repository would then serve on its own.

*What are the steps I need to take to be able to move to Github, without breaking the update system for the (albeit limited) users of my packages?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got a reply from NPM itself:

> Hi, Stephan.
>
> Thanks for the question. I'm hoping I can help...if I'm understanding
>   your inquiry correctly.
>
> What ever you publish to npm is held within our own repository and
>   that is what's served to a user when they install your package. The
>   inclusion of the repository url, bitbucket or github, is more
>   informational as opposed to functional. Regardless of when you push
>   changes to github, the user that installs your package will get your
>   latest publish to npm. In other words, those two things may be in
>   different states and at different versions.
>
> Please let me know if I'm off base. I'll be here to help. Ernie

In other words, for all I care I could remove the Bitbucket repository entire and nothing will break, as a copy is hosted on their servers which is served to everyone downloading it through NPM.

Thank you, Ernie!